# Restrict foreign key values according to request.user in django

Tags: django

I have declared a model Category and a model Post in my Blog application:

```
class Category(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  author = models.ForeignKey(User)
  desc = models.TextField(max_length=200, default='')

class Post(models.Model):

  author = models.ForeignKey(User)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=1)
  text = models.TextField()
```

What I want is to restrict the category foreign key in the Post model to the Categories where Category.author = Post.author. (Post author can select as Post Category only categories that he created).

What would be your approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to enforce choices on `ForeignKey` fields on database level is to use [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) argument.
You cannot do this to restrict `category` because queryset depends on request.

But you can access request object in ModelForm. So you'll have to override `__init__` of ModelForm to define custom queryset for `category`.

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Post

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
       super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       self.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(author=user)
```

Comment: Ok, I know that limit_choices argument is not good for dynamic restrictions, as the one I need. So your suggestion looks ok, but right now it doesn't work when I try to add a Post...I still see all the categories available!